# update perticular view in layout without affecting other views of layout

Tags: android-layout

[image]

I want to update only Linearlayout which between toolbar and edittext 
after every 3 sec, without affecting edittext, Is it possible? I have tried all ways but when schedular calls update method ,it clears edittext entered data also. How to stop this. Please Help me

Comment: Please add the code for your activity, and the layout as well.

Answer (score 0):

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chatList);

ll.invalidate();

Comment: Thank you but I'm not using listview. its linear layout and I'm adding view programatically in linearLayout.